# Press a button on a website using VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a code to be able to press a button on a website using VBA. This is the element I get by inspecting the website :

button class="btn btn-cta xs-liquid btn-progress pull-right l-margin-15-bottom" type="submit">verder.

There is no id for the element, I only get the class and type. How can I use these to be able to write an efficient code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the page is static (it does not change), then you can use GetElementsByTagName or GetElementsByClassName, and take the element with the zero-based index i from that collection: .Document.GetElementsByClassName("btn btn-cta xs-liquid btn-progress pull-right l-margin-15-bottom")(i).

In case of more complicated scenarios I would recommend XPath or CSS search.

Comment: I figured it out using your guidance ,  thanks a lot.